# What is the default password for SCOM 2019 VHD

Tags: window, windows-server-2019, scom

The VHD is downloaded from: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58057
But it does not mention the default password in the doc, anyone knows?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a set password for the VHD.

On first boot you set the password yourself.

[image: SCOM Eval Startup]